# Is there a way to create shortcut in VSCode that connects to remote jupyterhub server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-remote, jupyterhub

If I want to create kernel based on remote jupyterhub I need to do following:

1. press "Select Kernel"
2. press "Existing Jupyter Server..."
3. copy url address of server; copy my token; ~~figure out how to combine them~~; and press "Enter"

It seemed to me that it is possible to create a single shortcut for all these commands.

I tried to create it by myself, but I am stuck.

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+j",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "jupyter.switchToRemoteKernels",
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

It opens a prompt: [Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ysi.png)

I can't figure out how to paste predefined address to this prompt. I tried "type" command, but it does not work for this prompt (only for code and files)